# how to make a Choicefield invisible?

Tags: python, django, choicefield

I have two `ChoiceField`: the first one has two values and the second one should be invisible.

I would like to be able to show the second value when I click on the first one.

Any suggestion?

Comment: what have you tried? If you don't provide some more information and some code snippet, you risk getting the question closed

Comment: you will probably need to use some javascript `display=none` is the css to hide something ...

Answer (score 0):

@Joran is correct. You would need to use a JavaScript onChange event handler to show/hide the second select option. jQuery makes this trivial:

```
var first_select = $('#id_first_select'),
    second_select = $('#id_second_select');

first_select.change(function() {
    // Not checking for a particular value needed, etc.
    second_select.show();
});
```